# Image upload and download pperation In Spring boot web application using Thyemleaf, Image is not showing in web page

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, file-upload, thymeleaf

I'm trying to upload an image and display that image in web page. I'm using spring boot, thyemleaf and mysql.

When i run the application it working fine, image is uploading but image is not displaying/showing.

Project Structure

[image]

Model Class (Image.Java)

```
package com.example.Image;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.*;
@Entity
@Setter
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class Image {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    private String profilePicture;
    private long size;
    @Lob
    @Column(length = 1000)
    private byte [] content;
}
```

Controller Class (ImageController.java)

```
package com.example.Image;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

@Controller
public class ImageController {

    @Autowired
    private ImageDao dao;

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String home(Model model) {
        List<Image> list =  dao.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("list", list);
        return "home";
    }

    @PostMapping("/upload")
    public String fileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
        Image im = new Image();
        String fileName = file.getOriginalFilename();
        im.setProfilePicture(fileName);
        im.setContent(file.getBytes());
        im.setSize(file.getSize());
        dao.save(im);
        return "redirect:/";
    }
}
```

Dao Class (ImageDao.java)

```
package com.example.Image;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface ImageDao extends JpaRepository<Image,Long> {
}
```

Html page (Single page for uploading and displaying the image home.html)

```
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Image Download and Upload</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1><b>Image Upload and Download Operation</b></h1>
<form action="upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" >
<div>
    <h2><u>Upload Image</u></h2>
    <input type="file" name="file">
</div>
    <br>
    <div>
        <button type="submit">Upload</button>
</div>
</form>
<br><br>
<h2>Uploaded Images</h2>
<div>
    <th:block th:each="imgList: ${list}">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div><img th:src="@{'/image?id='+ ${imgList.id}}" width="50px" height="60px"></div>
            <div>[[${imgList.profilePicture}]]</div>
            <div>([[${imgList.size}*0.001]]) KB</div>
        </div>
    </th:block>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Database

Datatype view

[image]

Table view with data

[image]

Web view

[image]

Application.cofing

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/qq
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name = com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
spring.jpa.show-sql = true

#Multipart configuration
spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=true
spring.servlet.multipart.file-size-threshold=2KB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=200MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=215MB
```

How to display the image in web page?

I'm trying to upload the image and showing it in web page. Uploading is happening, but it is not showing in web page.

Comment: Where is your code to handle the image endpoint defined by `th:src="@{'/image?id='+ ${imgList.id}}"`? And what HTML actually gets generated by that fragment of Thymeleaf?

Comment: Minor point: Do you really have a file called `Application.cofing`? I assume that's just a typo in the question.